# Recyclerview multiple view type with dynamic header

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm familiar with `RecyclerView` multiple view items.

Recently I came across about adding a dynamic header based on some criteria.
I'm trying to make a sense with given data but my logic does not seem work

Here, I have a custom list which has 4 items

```
{"en":"Candy"}, name='c1', id= 1}
{"en":"Bar"}, name='c2', id= 2}
{"en":"Bar"}, name='c3', id= 3 }
{"en":"Donut"}, name='c4', id= 4}
```

Now, how to write a condition in `getViewType(intposition)`, so that resultant output with header view.

```
Candy
tv -> c1   tv->id1

Bar
tv ->c2     tv->id2 
tv ->c3     tv->id3

Donut
tv ->c4     tv -> id4
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I have never worked on adding a dynamic header.

Comment: Can you please check the answer and let me know if that helps?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the list items appear sequentially. Then after a list of `Candy`, you will have a list of `Bar` and then a list of `Donut` and so on. I have a similar implementation [here in Github](https://github.com/masudias/dynamic-recyclerview) where you might get the idea of how you can implement this using different view types.

I would like the suggest having different lists parsed from the original list like the following.

```
ArrayList<Sweet> candyList = getAllCandiesFromTheOriginalList();
ArrayList<Sweet> barList = getAllBarsFromTheOriginalList();
ArrayList<Sweet> donutList = getAllDonutsFromTheOriginalList();
```

Once you have all the list, you can track down the size of each of your individual lists and get the view type accordingly in your `getItemViewType` function.

```
// Initialize these variables in the constructor of your adapter
// Make these variables global, so that it can be used from other functions. 
int candyListSize = candyList.size();
int barListSize = barList.size();
int donutListSize = donutList.size();
int totalSize = candyListSize + barListSize + donutListSize;

int CANDY_HEADER_TYPE = 99;
int BAR_HEADER_TYPE = 98;
int DONUT_HEADER_TYPE = 97;

// I assume that candy, bar, and donut comes sequentially in your RecyclerView
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {

    if (position == 0) return CANDY_HEADER_TYPE;
    else if (position == candyListSize + 1) return BAR_HEADER_TYPE;
    else if (position == candyListSize + barListSize + 2) return DONUT_HEADER_TYPE;

    return super.getItemViewType(position);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return totalSize + 3; // As there will be 3 extra headers.
}
```

You need to implement your `onBindViewHolder` intelligently as well.

This might not give you the exact solution to the problem you are having. However, I hope this helps to understand how you can solve the problem.

Comment: Hi Reaz,  thanks for taking your time into this,  firstly list is sorted out and dynamic, the array sample which I provided above is dynamic, means after donut, it can be anything, so VIEW TYPE can't be hardcoded for each types.

Comment: solved, it's more of a logic in loop, had to sort all items